# FnToProduct not working with a Type Constructor

Tags: scala, shapeless, type-constructor

Why does this works as expected:

```
def method1[L <: HList, M <: HList, F, R](list: L)(builder: F)
           (implicit ev: Comapped.Aux[L, Seq, M],
           fntp: FnToProduct.Aux[F, M => R]) = println("asd")

method1(Seq("asd") :: HNil) { (s: String) =>
  6
}
```

But this does not?

```
def method2[L <: HList, M <: HList, F, R](list: L)(builder: F)
           (implicit ev: Comapped.Aux[L, Seq, M],
           fntp: FnToProduct.Aux[F, M => Seq[R]]) = println("asd")

method2(Seq("asd") :: HNil) { (s: String) =>
  Seq(6)
}
```

It seems that adding a type constructor in the return type for the FnToProduct.Aux breaks it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that when the compiler is trying to infer the type parameters for `method1`, it's going to find `L` and `M` and `F` with no problems, but then when it gets to `R` it's not going to be able to tell that the second parameter of the `FnToProduct.Aux` has the right shape to line up with `M => Seq[R]`.

Off the top of my head I don't have a good explanation of why this happens in the second case and not the first, but it's a limitation you'll run into fairly often, and there are a couple of workarounds.

The first would be to leave the `Aux` off of the `FnToProduct` altogether. Depending on what your actual method is doing, this may be just fine, but if you need to refer to `R` explicitly it's not going to work.

The second workaround would be to let the return type of that second type parameter be inferred, and then ask for evidence that it's a `Seq`:

```
import shapeless._, ops.function.FnToProduct, ops.hlist.Comapped

def method2[L <: HList, M <: HList, F, S, R](list: L)(builder: F)
  (implicit
    ev: Comapped.Aux[L, Seq, M],
    fntp: FnToProduct.Aux[F, M => S],
    s: S <:< Seq[R]
  ) = println("asd")

method2(Seq("asd") :: HNil) { (s: String) => Seq(6) }
```

It's a little extra syntactic noise, but it works.